# move services between windows azure datacenters

Tags: azure

I believe that there's no easy way, but it doesn't hurt ask for you guys.

Is there a way to move services (websites, cloudaps, etc) between datacenters without re-create and re-deploy them?

For example: I have a website in West US and I want to move to Europe.

(by the way I suggest this to azure team and I hope you can vote for it http://feedback.windowsazure.com/forums/34192-general-feedback-/suggestions/5071811-move-services-from-datacenters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Gaurav suggested, you can try to put in a support ticket with Microsoft.  I'm assuming you'll need a support plan though in order to get that through, since this isn't really a billing related issue.

Other than going that route, there is nothing today that will move services (websites, cloud services, etc.) from one datacenter to another.

Comment: FYI, the Azure support team is not able to do this.  This type of move requires a redeploy.